# Power BI DAX iterator functions escape context

Tags: powerbi

I am leaning Power BI DAX iterator functions, got confused when to use a "measure" as the expression of a iterator function:

Say we firstly define a measure:

```
Quantity = SUM(Sales[Order Quantity])
```

then following two measures are not returning same results:

```
Product Quantity Rank = 
RANKX(
    ALL('Product'[Product]),
    [Quantity]
)
```

&

```
Product Quantity Rank too = 
RANKX(
    ALL('Product'[Product]),
    SUM(Sales[Order Quantity])
)
```

[image]

The second measure escaped row context. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your second measure correct, you have to apply a CALCULATE to your aggregation as below-

```
Product Quantity Rank too = 
RANKX(
    ALL('Product'[Product]),
    CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Order Quantity]))
)
```

A very good explanation can be found [HERE](https://radacad.com/how-to-use-rankx-in-dax-part-2-of-3-calculated-measures)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw it is not only for RANKX , for any iterator functions it has the same issue. I reckon when using measure as the expression, CALCULATE function been used implictly.

Comment: You are most welcom.  Nice to see it helped.

Answer (score 1):

By lookup different materials, finally figured out this is an issue of "context transition".

```
SUM(Sales[Order Quantity])
```

in

```
Product Quantity Rank too = 
RANKX(
    ALL('Product'[Product]),
    SUM(Sales[Order Quantity])
)
```

actually sum up every "Order Quantity" in sales table.

When using the CALCULATE function it applies row context values as filters, known as "context transition".

If you reference measures in an expression that's evaluated in row context, context transition is automatic. Thus, you don't need to pass measure references to the CALCULATE function.

Therefore, both

```
Product Quantity Rank = 
RANKX(
    ALL('Product'[Product]),
    [Quantity]
)
```

and

```
Product Quantity Rank too = 
RANKX(
    ALL('Product'[Product]),
    CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Order Quantity]))
)
```

works